# node.js объеденение функций в класс

Tags: node.js

Как говорят глупых вопросов не бывает =) Мне требуется объединить несколько функций под один класс в одном файле *js. И теперь подробнее...

`file.js`

```js
async function one () {}
async function two () {}
module.exports = { one, two }
```

обращаться к этим функция будем так:

`index.js`

```js
const func = requare('./file');

func.one();
```

как мне реорганизовать файл чтоб я мог обращаться к функции `one()` таким образом:

```js
const func = requare('./file');

func.className.one();
```

Ранее получилось добиться этого обернув один файл в другой :

`index.js`

```js
const func = requare('./file');
func.className.one();
```

`file.js`

```js
const className = requare('./file_2');
module.exports = { className }
```

`file_2.js`

```js
async function one () {}
async function two () {}
module.exports = { one, two }
```

Но не думаю что это адекватный вариант... Буду благодарен за помощь в реорганизации подобного кода!

Comment: `module.exports = { className: { one, two } }`...

Comment: у меня есть некоторое количество функций которые формируют ответ от api. Чтобы не подключать этот модуль везде где нужно сформировать ответ я хочу подключить этот модуль как плагин fastify и формировать ответ запросом  ```fastify.response.ok();```. Сейчас испробую ваш вариант. Заранее спасибо за помощь! =)

Comment: Ну или так https://jsfiddle.net/kq2vh3md/

Comment: да, второй вариант подходит отлично для моей задачи. Если хотите, добавьте ответ, я его отмечу =) Спасибо еще раз )